# Javascript - Getting removed item name from table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an table. By click of a button, information will be added there, so each item has also X button, which removes them from the list. I've been trying to do that, if you click that X button, then it will output to console the item name which you deleted. How could I do that?

Here's the function

```
function sitaSeen(img, name, condition, price) {
  $('tbody').append("<tr id='itemCart'><td><img src=" + img + "></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + condition + "</td><td>$" + price + "</td><td><span>X</span></td></tr>");
```

Which is called, when item has to be added.

Here's the X button code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sweet-container').on('click', 'tr span', function(){
        var removedname = $(this).closest('tr').ignore('span').text();
        console.log(removedname);
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

There's also kind of my try, but ofc it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `ignore()` method in jQuery so it will throws error in console. So either clone the `tr` and remove `span` from cloned object and then get text or get all td which is not contains `span` and get text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sweet-container').on('click', 'tr span', function(){
        var removedname = $(this).closest('tr').clone().remove('span').text();
        // or
        // var removedname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:has(span))').text();
        console.log(removedname);
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE :** Since you just want the second column you can simply use **[`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** or **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector(or **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sweet-container').on('click', 'tr span', function(){
        var removedname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        // or
        // $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
        // or
        // $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(1).text();
        console.log(removedname);
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! It works, only one problem that it gets all of the values. Like the table has 3 values, name condition & price then it outputs them all.

Comment: @AleksKpur : ok which column do you want to get actually?

Comment: Name column so the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better to use:

```
// better way to get to the tr element

var trElem = $(this).parentNode.parentNode;
```

The parentNode attribute is a better way to access the parent of an element.

Answer (score 0):

The item name is the second td so you can use:

```
var removedname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

Because the ID have to be unique I added a new parameter to your function.

```js
function sitaSeen(seq, img, name, condition, price) {
  $('tbody').append("<tr id='itemCart" + seq + "'>" +
                    "<td><img src=" + img + "></td>" +
                    "<td>" + name + seq + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + condition + "</td>" +
                    "<td>$" + price + "</td>" +
                    "<td><span>X</span></td>" +
                    "</tr>");
}
$(function () {
  $('#addRow').on('click', function(e) {
    var seq = +$(this).attr('data-seq');
    $(this).attr('data-seq', seq + 1);
    sitaSeen(seq, 'img', 'name', 'condition', 'price');
  });

  $('.sweet-container').on('click', 'tr span', function(){
    var removedname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    console.log(removedname);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="sweet-container">
    <button id="addRow" data-seq="1">Add Row</button>
    <table>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```